# Any irreducible projective curve in $\mathbb P^3$ can be defined by three functions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Suppose $C$ is a irreducible closed curve in $\mathbb P^3$(projective space over an algebraically closed field), I need to prove there are three homogeneous functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ such that $C=V_+(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. How to get it?

Comment: An idea that I have is to look at the cone in $\mathbb{A}^4$, and then use the fact that if $p\subset B$ is a prime ideal for some 'nice' domain $B$, then:  ht($p$)+dim($B/p$)=dim($B$). You might need to work a little more to show that we have homogeneous generators

Comment: @CoherentSheaf Yes, but I need to find 3 generators which is larger than the height. How to find it?

Comment: Are you assuming smoothness?

Comment: @user10354138 No

Comment: I remember that if I have a smooth subvariety of a smooth variety, it can always be cut out by a section of a vector bundle but this result is stronger and I don’t know the proof.